# In which step does AES use the key to encrypt data?

Tags: encryption, aes

AES has the following steps in encryption: SubBytes, ShiftRows, MixColumns, and AddRoundKey and the following steps in decryption: InvSubBytes, InvShiftRows, InvMixColumns, and Inverse of AddRoundKey.

My question is: in which step of encryption and decryption is the key used to encrypt and decrypt data?

Comment: How was that not explicitly clear by the names of the steps?

Answer (score 2):

AddRoundKey.

That step takes 16 bytes from the expanded key schedule, and exclusive-or's ("adds" in $GF(256)$ terminology) it to the intermediate block state.